# Why did my app stop supporting screen orientation changes?

Tags: android, orientation

I created a new Android application with a basic Toast message and options menu.  For a while the app supported orientation changes without issue, but now it seems to no longer care about auto-rotating.  Is there some magic setting that I wiped or set without knowing it?  The literally has had no code changes since I first created it and it worked without issue.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.somedomain.appname"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".StartActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**StartActivity.java**

```
package com.somedomain.appname;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

/** Main Activity **/
public class AppName extends Activity {

    /** Called when someone specifies to view the options menu **/
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Set
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.navigate, menu);

        // Return
        return true;
    }

    /* Handle options menu selections */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.itemNewGame:
                // New Game
                return true;
            case R.id.itemSettings:
                // Settings
                return true;
            case R.id.itemAbout:
                // About
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Super
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      

        // First time?
        if ( savedInstanceState == null ) // null the first time
        {        
            // Splash
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1));
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

**splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">      
    <ImageView 
android:src="@drawable/logo" src="@drawable/logo" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:padding="30dip"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Where is `frameLayout1` defined?

Comment: Sorry, updated to show the splash.xml file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check if you have rotation enable on phone, sometimes I forgot it too :P

Comment: Sooooo correct.  Wow I don't know how I missed this obvious cause.  Well at least this will serve both as a hard lesson for me and others and also as a good reference for a starting point for an app :)